# Appcenter failed to build Android React Native build due to Jetifier

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-app-center, android-jetifier

I have React Native project with CI Appcenter integration
Due to Jetifier warn build always fails

I tried to use

```
android.useAndroidX=false
android.enableJetifier=false
```

but build fails, because I need androidx migrations.

I also tried to use

```
"@react-native-community/cli": "^12.0.0-alpha.3"
```

which should not use Jetifier, but Appcenter seems to force run Jetifier anyway

Any solution to this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/887#issuecomment-1103251628), you can replace your jetifier version with the last 1.x

```bash
yarn add -D jetifier@1.x
```